# How to debug cider on emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I have an issue using cider: emacs freezes after `nREPL server started on 54308` is written. `C-g` helps, but I have cider not working. My question is: how can I debug cider and get some usefull output to find the source of this problem?

P.S. After a long time I get `error in process filter: error during connect: connection timed out`. But I would like to debug underlying process (as `nrepl-server` is started).

Answer (score 2):

`M-x toggle-debug-on-error` should make it easy to obtain the stacktrace of the problem. After that you can you use any general debugging technique (personally, I'm fond using the debugger). I see you've also reported your problem [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/794) - that's always a good idea.